# CSS capitalize whole sentence except for a specific string

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let say I have the following strings.

i and we.
me and you.
he and she.

Is there a workaround using which I can get the following result using PURE CSS?

**I** and **We.**
**Me** and **You**.
**He** and **She**.

If I use text-transform: capitalize then it will obviously give.

I **And** We.
Me **And** You.
He **And** She.

Any way to skip "**and**" by the capitalization? I know I can do it via jQuery but you never know the power of CSS. So its worth asking the experts first before writing a script.

Thank you.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Please consider that I don't have the access to change the markup. So I can't write

i `<span class="skip">`and`</span>` we.
me `<span class="skip">`and`</span>` you.
he `<span class="skip">`and`</span>` she.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

CSS can't manipulate the DOM and/or target a small part of an element.

Comment: Which means I'll have to go to the big manipulator. jQuery :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible in CSS3.
As far as I know, you cannot target arbitrary parts of an element with CSS selectors.

The only things I've seen so far that allow you to target part of an element are [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) and [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line).
Now, the only thing you can really do with those is capitalize the first word of an element, using

```css
div::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!-- just for demo: -->
<div>herp derp</div>
```

However, you would at the very least need something like `::last-word` (if one line of text you provided was encapsulated in an element), or `::nth-line()::last-word` or even `::nth-word()` (if they are all in the same element).
However, none of these exist (yet).

So unless you can modify the markup, your only option for now is to go with JavaScript.